# WooCommerce: Automatically add & remove product tag & category based on product stock status

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

In WooCommerce I am trying to automatically add & remove the Product Tag & Category (Out of Stock) based on the current Product Stock Status.

I'm using [Automatically add a specific category and tags to a product when it goes out of stock after the order is placed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62189045/11987538) answer code  but it's not working for me, can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you found those 'woocommerce_no_stock' and 'woocommerce_in_stock' but i think they do not exist.

What you can do, instead, is using these two:

```
[....]
// Fire actions to let 3rd parties know the stock changed.
if ( $product_with_stock->is_type( 'variation' ) ) {
    do_action( 'woocommerce_variation_set_stock', $product_with_stock );
} else {
    do_action( 'woocommerce_product_set_stock', $product_with_stock );
}
```

'woocommerce_variation_set_stock' and 'woocommerce_product_set_stock' will pass to your callback function the product_id on which the stock qty is getting reduced after and order is placed. You can get the current value of the stock with:

```
get_post_meta($product_with_stock,'_stock',true);
```

and then you can understand if it is in stock or not (or just check the current stock_status with $product->get_stock_status().

After all of this, you can try to apply your logic